# Are mathematical translations on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, languages

[Translating an Italian exercise precisely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664329/italian-speaking-mathematician-translating-an-exercise-precisely)

It seems a little off-topic, but I wanted to ask here. The problem is it seems rather specialized, and requires a good deal of non-mathematical knowledge.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6690/translation-of-mathematical-questions)

Comment: Conversely, it does require *some* mathematical knowledge. I just grabbed some of the words and asked Google Translate, and got back "and $f: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ linear transformation and suppose that $f$ matrix associated to the base $\mathcal{B} = \{\ldots\}$ of domain and range ($e_i$ are carriers of the canonical base)" and for part d), "it is a basic calculations space zero linear application $f$." Probably any human would do a bit better than Google Translate, but that last part is absolutely worthless, when it should be talking about finding a basis for the null space.

Comment: This has been asked in the past and the consensus was that translation requests are on-topic.

Answer (score 11):

I would say *yes* on the basis that this sort of question is helpful to future readers who are trying to interpret the odd untranslated foreign-language mathematical text.

Good answers to these types of questions might help you fill in the blanks for what your foreign-language-speaking friend or Google Translate could not illuminate.

Comment: A related question I asked a while ago: [Am I missing out by not knowing another language?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794055/am-i-missing-out-by-not-knowing-another-language/1659083#1659083)

Comment: Giving your reasoning it seems especially important though to insist the to be translated text is typed in and not only presented as  a scan (though a scan can be a useful backup).